# PostgreSQL idle_in_transaction_session_timeout seems to have no effect

Tags: postgresql, transactions, timeout, postgresql-10

I'm working with a PostgreSQL server version 10.5 (can't upgrade it at the moment) running in Docker. XL Deploy is connected to it and I upload a new archive that is 232MB. I get the error `FATAL:  terminating connection due to idle-in-transaction timeout`.

In the config, I saw that `idle_in_transaction_session_timeout` was set to 11000ms. I updated the value to 600000ms and reload the configuration. I see the message `LOG:  parameter "idle_in_transaction_session_timeout" changed to "600000"` in the logs, so I know the setting has taken.

However, when I upload the archive again, I still get the same FATAL timeout message. It's as if the setting is having no effect.

Comment: I think it can be set from the client end too - perhaps check what the setting is in your client code.

Answer (score 4):

As it turns out, the issue was in Postgres, but not in the config file. It seems you can update the value of `idle_in_transaction_session_timeout` at various levels. In my case, it was at the ROLE level. Issuing this SQL statement fixed the timeout.

```sql
ALTER ROLE role_abc SET idle_in_transaction_session_timeout = '10min';
```

Comment: how can you detect this was set on the role level? `pg_dumball --globals-only` comes to mind.

Comment: I don't know. Just trial and error.